# iOS - take screenshot of UIScrollView visible area with Size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I found this code which works perfectly. But it uses the size of the scrollview. I want to use the my size.

```
UIScrollView *contentScrollView;....//scrollview instance

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contentScrollView.bounds.size, 
                                       YES, 
                                       [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

//this is the key
CGPoint offset=contentScrollView.contentOffset;
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y); 

[contentScrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *visibleScrollViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If I want to use my CGSize, what should I use for `CGContextTranslateCTM` ?

**EDIT**

My `scrollView` size is 350 x 350. I added an `imageView` as its subview.
The user can zoom and scroll the scrollView.

After the user is done zooming/scrolling the user can click the save button. This button takes a screen shot of my `scrollView`

From the above code. My screen shot image size is 350 x 350 (same size as the `scrollView`). I would like to take a screenshot of the scrollView with size 1040 x 1040 and get the correct zooming/scrolling area.

I know that I can change the size by doing this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1040, 1040), YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
```

But I do not know how to change the offset part according to the new size.

Comment: you can pass the CGSize to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgV.frame.size);

Comment: Yes I know this. The thing is my scrollview will get zoomed. I do not know how to set the offset for the result image. If you do know the answer, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @imstillalive So you're not trying to change the size of the resultant image, you just want to provide a custom offset to define the portion of the scroll view to render?

Comment: @originaluser2 I have edited my question. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [`drawViewHierarchyInRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:), you can skip messing about with the content offset and scale to begin with. It will simply render the visible area of the scroll view in a given rect.

This will allow you to pass in your custom size, and it will be scaled up or down accordingly.

For example:

```
CGSize size = (CGSize){1040, 1040};

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
[scrollView drawViewHierarchyInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, size} afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If you still want to render the layer yourself, then you just have to scale the context according to the ratio of your new size to the size of the scroll view (as `renderInContext` uses the layer's size, not the context's size), and then offset by the content offset.

For example:

```
CGSize size = (CGSize){1040, 1040};

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, size.width/scrollView.bounds.size.width, size.height/scrollView.bounds.size.height);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -scrollView.contentOffset.x, -scrollView.contentOffset.y);
[scrollView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```